# Sort numpy array using two arguments

Tags: python, sorting, numpy

A small snippet of a data set I have is the following:

```
import numpy

fns = numpy.array(["filename_0004_0003_info.hdf5", "filename_0003_0003_info.hdf5", "filename_0001_0001_info.hdf5", "filename_0002_0001_info.hdf5", "filename_0006_0002_info.hdf5", "filename_0005_0002_info.hdf5"])
```

The first integer I call `run`, whereas the second integer I denote as `order`. I want to sort this data set. First based on the `order` number, and second based on the `run` number. Every `order` number exists twice while the `run` number is unique. When I only sort based on the `order` number using `numpy.argsort()`:

```
order_nrs = numpy.array([int(fn.split("_")[2]) for fn in fns])
fns = numpy.copy(fns)[numpy.argsort(order_nrs)]
```

I obtain

```
['filename_0001_0001_info.hdf5' 'filename_0002_0001_info.hdf5' 'filename_0006_0002_info.hdf5' 'filename_0005_0002_info.hdf5' 'filename_0004_0003_info.hdf5' 'filename_0003_0003_info.hdf5']
```

Although `fns` is sorted based on `order` it should afterwards also be sorted by `run`. The results should be:

```
filename_0001_0001_info.hdf5
filename_0002_0001_info.hdf5
filename_0005_0002_info.hdf5
filename_0006_0002_info.hdf5
filename_0003_0003_info.hdf5
filename_0004_0003_info.hdf5
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Can I ask why you're converting to a numpy array to do this sort? Why not sort the list and then convert to an array if you need it?

Comment: A minor comment is that it would help readability if filenames were a bit shorter in your example. Or if you broke the `fns =` line

Comment: looks like a job for [`np.lexsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html)

Comment: @DanielF How would you go about approaching the problem using `np.lexsort`?

Answer (score 0):

```
fns = ["filename_0004_0003_info.hdf5", "filename_0003_0003_info.hdf5", "filename_0001_0001_info.hdf5", "filename_0002_0001_info.hdf5", "filename_0006_0002_info.hdf5", "filename_0005_0002_info.hdf5"]


def sortfunc(s):
    words = s.split('_')
    run, order = int(words[1]), int(words[2])
    return order, run

fns.sort(key=sortfunc)
```

Comment: This doesn't use `numpy` at all and there's more elegant ways of sorting a pure python list.

Answer (score 0):

A bit verbose, but useful to see the 'order' parameter in argsort.

```
fns = np.array(["filename_0004_0003_info.hdf5", "filename_0003_0003_info.hdf5", "filename_0001_0001_info.hdf5", "filename_0002_0001_info.hdf5",
     "filename_0006_0002_info.hdf5", "filename_0005_0002_info.hdf5"])

o = np.array([fn.split("_") for fn in fns])
a_r = np.core.records.fromarrays(o.transpose(),
                                     names=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
                                     formats=['U9']*4)
idx = np.argsort(a_r, order=['c', 'b'])

out = fns[idx]

out
Out[22]: 
array(['filename_0001_0001_info.hdf5', 'filename_0002_0001_info.hdf5',
       'filename_0005_0002_info.hdf5', 'filename_0006_0002_info.hdf5',
       'filename_0003_0003_info.hdf5', 'filename_0004_0003_info.hdf5'],
      dtype='<U28')
```

Start with the filenames, split on the `_` as you have done, convert to a recarray or structured array (a simple example given), use argsort but order on the two numeric types you want to use... and use the `idx` index to reorder the original.
There are probably other elegant ways, but I like to see exactly what is going on and `argsort` order property makes it clear for me.  To bad you just can't use an index number instead of the named fields

Answer (score 0):

One way is engineering the dtype such that only the two numbers are visible and the second comes first:

```
>>> fns = numpy.array(["filename_0004_0003_info.hdf5", "filename_0003_0003_info.hdf5", "filename_0001_0001_info.hdf5", "filename_0002_0001_info.hdf5", "filename_0006_0002_info.hdf5", "filename_0005_0002_info.hdf5"])
>>> fns.view(np.dtype({'names':['f1','f2'], 'formats':['<U4','<U4'], 'offsets':[56,36], 'itemsize':112})).sort()
>>> fns
array(['filename_0001_0001_info.hdf5', 'filename_0002_0001_info.hdf5',
       'filename_0005_0002_info.hdf5', 'filename_0006_0002_info.hdf5',
       'filename_0003_0003_info.hdf5', 'filename_0004_0003_info.hdf5'],
      dtype='<U28')
```

This is direct inplace sort, but `argsort`, of course, also works.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `np.lexsort`, it uses a stable sort on a series of keys to do what you want.